# join 3 tables (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, join, case

I want to join 3 tables (t1, t2, t3). I need to keep t1 (items and their properties) as it is (LEFT JOIN).

Table t1 references t2 in order to retrieve more properties for each t1.item. However, in t2 there can be multiple entries of t1.item references each with individual values, ie. item1 (value1,value2), item2 (value3,value4), item1 (value5,value6) and so on. Table t2 contains refrences itself to t3 - t2 has a column named "style" with properties represented by numbers that need to be looked up in t3 (ie. number 1 --> property1, number 2 --> property2 etc.). For the task at hand I only want style properties with the reference number "1". The following code seems to do the trick:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                       FROM 
                         t1 
                       LEFT JOIN 
                         (t2 INNER JOIN t3 ON t2.id= t3.id) 
                       ON t1.id=t2.id AND t2.type='1' 
                       ORDER BY t1.item $order ");
```

The thing is, there can still be two or more items with the same t1 refrence that have this same style attached to them, ie. item1 (value1, value2, style1), item1 (value3, value4, style1). Out of these items I want to extract only one, namely the one with the highest value. First I need to check each item's value pair and retrieve the highest amount out of those and then I need to compare those two item values. Something like this:

```
(CASE WHEN MAX(t2.column_value1) > MAX(t2.column_value2) 
      THEN t2.column_value1 
      ELSE t2.column_value2 END)
```

I just don't know how to put this to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

UPDATE: This seems to Work now (I’d still be grateful for any improvement suggestions, though):

```
    SELECT casinos.id, casinos.casino,
    bonus.amount, bonus.match, bonus_type_lookup.bonus_id,
    bonus_type_lookup.bonus_type 
    FROM casinos 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (bonus INNER JOIN bonus_type_lookup ON bonus.bonus_type =  bonus_type_lookup.bonus_id) ON casinos.id=bonus.id AND bonus.bonus_type='1' AND ((bonus.amount = (SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(bonus.amount) > MAX(bonus.match) OR (MAX(bonus.match) IS NULL) THEN MAX(bonus.amount) ELSE MAX(bonus.match) END FROM bonus WHERE casinos.id=bonus.id AND bonus.bonus_type='1')) OR (bonus.match = (SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(bonus.amount) > MAX(bonus.match) THEN MAX(bonus.amount) ELSE MAX(bonus.match) END FROM bonus WHERE casinos.id=bonus.id AND bonus.bonus_type='1'))) 
    GROUP BY casinos.casino 
    ORDER BY 
    CASE 
       WHEN bonus.amount > bonus.match THEN bonus.amount
       WHEN bonus.match IS NULL THEN bonus.amount
       ELSE bonus.match
    END DESC
```

The "GROUP BY casino.casino(name)" statement seems to take care of limiting the results to only one row per unique_id in case there are multiple equal values? Example: (row1 -> casino A, signup, match:200, amount:50); row2 -> casino A, signup, match:50, amount:200) In both cases the MAX(value) would be 200, but I only need one. 
I think only the 1st row is kept regardless of any values.

Comment: can you post some sample data and the expected result?  It is difficult to decipher what you are looking for with this word problem.

Comment: `code` $result = mysql_query("SELECT 
casinos.id, casinos.casino, 

bonus.amount, bonus.match, 
bonus_type_lookup.bonus_id, bonus_type_lookup.bonus_type
 
FROM casinos LEFT JOIN  
(bonus INNER JOIN bonus_type_lookup ON bonus.bonus_type = bonus_type_lookup.bonus_id) ON casinos.id=bonus.id AND bonus.bonus_type='1' 
ORDER BY casinos.casino $order 
");
`code` The reult should be something like this: name, bonus_type1, value(as number or percent, depending which one is higher). Hope that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: this is still not clear. best would be to put sample data to show the example and then put the expected results. if possible, make it on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2 and post back the link to your data

Comment: can you post dummy data and table structure for better understanding ?

Comment: SQLfiddle is a good suggestion, but with my background I’m lost, sorry. Maybe we could stick to the part that gets the overall max bonuses (type=1) value (either “match” or “amount”) out of multiple rows? There can be multiple rows with the same casino and bonus fields (amount,match). I only want to pick the one with the highest value-either the amount OR the match. This should select the max value,but how to put it as condition?

(SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(bonus.amount) > MAX(bonus.match) THEN bonus.amount ELSE bonus.match END FROM bonus WHERE casinos.id=bonus.id AND bonus.bonus_type='1') Thanks